# Current Density Equations in Finite Element Analysis

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, computational-physics

I'm trying to set up a simple finite element simulation for a homogeneous bulk material with small contacts (compared to the bulk). I provide the potential at the contacts and my goal is to compute the spatially resolved current density within the material.

I am not entirely sure which equations to use though... I have seen some people use Poisson's equation:
$$ \Delta \Phi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon} $$
with $\Phi$ the potential, $\rho$ the carrier density, and $\epsilon$ the permittivity. From $\Phi$, they then compute the electric field $\vec{E}$ which is supposed to be proportional to the current density according to Ohm's law.

But isn't Poisson's equation supposed to describe the electrostatic case? I'm confused here. Is the above procedure valid when I am interested in current flow, an inherently dynamic and not static process?

Comment: You need to use Laplace as you have a static electric field set up in a conductor through which the charge carriers flow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, a steady state current is a static situation which is why the above procedure can be applied?

Comment: @lmr steady state current is not static situation, but a *stationary* situation. The electrostatic formulae are valid even then, as long as charges do not accelerate too  rapidly.